# How to use M_LN2 from Math.h

Tags: c, constants, c99, math.h

I am trying to use the Constant M_LN2 from the math.h library but always seem to get a compiler error. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

double x = M_LN2;
printf("%e",x);

return 0;
}
```

compiling with gcc on ubuntu

```
gcc -std=c99 lntester.c -o lntester -lm
```

getting output:

```
error: 'M_LN2' undeclared
```

any help in understanding why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

As stated below the if def were not getting defined and using gcc and c99 were causing the issue.   Below is the compile code that solved the issue and allowed me to use c99.

```
gcc -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE lntested.c -o lntester -lm
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> any help in understanding why this is happening would be greatly
>   appreciated.

You can open `/usr/include/math.h` and try to found definition of `M_LN2`. For me it is defined and wrapped by condition macros:

```
#if defined __USE_BSD || defined __USE_XOPEN
...
# define M_LN2          0.69314718055994530942  /* log_e 2 */
...
#endif
```

When you compile your code with option `-std=c99` neither `__USE_BSD` no `__USE_XOPEN` defined, so all variables which wrapped by `if define` not defined too.

You can compile your code without `-std=c99` option or with `-std=gnu99` option instead.

Comment: Okay, so i have posted the solution to the issue in the code.  Thanks for helping understand that the if defs were the reason it was happening.